# Why does the first element not work?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In my `urls.py` file, the first element doesn't work at all. What the hell?

Here's my *original* `urls.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
)
```

Set up like that, I can't access /admin/, *modifying* it to...

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^wutlolwutwut/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
)
```

It now does. The Debug from the 404 on the *original* doesn't show the admin regex.

Proof with [*original*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpAFu.png), and with [*modified*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujFHk.png).

What is happenning?

**SOLVED:** `pattern()` function takes *a* `string` *prefix as it's first argument* along `n` number of `url()` calls, which is what bugged my urls.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to the `patterns` function should be a string that acts as a prefix for the remaining arguments.

Comment: Gosh, I'm such an idiot. So that's what the empty string `''` next to the `pattern(` meant...